# How to set swagger basePath in ASP.NET Web Api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I have enabled swagger documentation for an ASP.NET web application. How to set the basePath?

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration .EnableSwagger(c => { 
    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "MyApi") .Description("This is my API."); 
    c.IncludeXmlComments($@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\bin\MyApi.XML");
}) .EnableSwaggerUi(c => {});
```

Currently the generated API description is as follows:

```
"swagger": "2.0",
"host": "localhost:8080",
"basePath": "/",
```

I want to change it to:

```
"swagger": "2.0",
"host": "localhost:8080",
"basePath": "/myapi",
```

Comment: Can you share some of your code?

Comment: Add a reference to Swashbuckle nuget package that automatically adds swaggerConfig.cs file to App_Start folder. The swagger UI and JSON document are perfectly fine. I just want to set the basePath. `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .EnableSwagger(c =>
        {
     c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "MyApi")
      .Description("This is my API.");

            c.IncludeXmlComments($@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\bin\MyApi.XML");
        })
    .EnableSwaggerUi(c => {});`

Comment: Other things are commented by default. I pasted only the currently used (uncommented) code. It's too huge to paste it here; stackoverflow doesn't allow. It doesn't even allow to upload files. Please create a new ASP.NET Web Api project and add reference to swashbuckle. Otherwise give me your email id, I'll email you the file.

Comment: go over the comments see if something stands out... I think what you need is RootUrl

Comment: Before posting a question on stackoverflow, I tried everything but couldn't find any solution. The purpose of RootUrl is "By default, the service root url is inferred from the request used to access the docs. However, there may be situations (e.g. proxy and load-balanced environments) where this does not resolve correctly. You can workaround this by providing your own code to determine the root URL.". Have you implemented swagger documentation in any of your projects? Do you know the exact solution to set the basePath for an ASP.NET Web API?

Comment: Yes I have implemented swagger on many projects, but your question is not very detailed, so no, I do not know the exact solution to your problem.

Comment: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1443. I want to do similar thing in an ASP.NET Web API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add **RootUrl** to your config, something like:

```cs
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration .EnableSwagger(c => { 
    
    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "MyApi") .Description("This is my API."); 
    
    c.IncludeXmlComments($@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\bin\MyApi.XML");
    
    c.RootUrl(req => { return "http://localhost:8080/myapi"; });
    
}) .EnableSwaggerUi(c => {});
```

Comment: This added basePath to the swagger document but instead of redirecting "/swagger" to "/swagger/ui/index", it is redirecting to "/myapi/swagger/ui/index" which gives 404 error. I'm able to directly browse to "/swagger/ui/index" but again it gives an error "Can't read swagger JSON from http://localhost:7183/myapi/swagger/docs/v1".

Comment: One more issue is that it will just add "/myapi" as basePath but doesn't remove the same from the individual APIs. This can be fixed by manually editing the JSON document or by updating the document using powershell.

Comment: @Venky you should not have to do anything outside swashbuckle, look into IDocumentFilters to transform the swagger json

Comment: I commented out setting RootUrl; Now my swagger UI is back. Used DocumentFilter to set the basePath to "/myapi" and remove the same from each path. I don't know if it is the right way to do or not but it fixed all my issues. Thanks a ton @HelderSepu. You rock. `swaggerDoc.basePath = "/myapi";
var paths = swaggerDoc.paths.ToList();
foreach (var path in paths)
{
    swaggerDoc.paths.Remove(path.Key);
    swaggerDoc.paths.Add(path.Key.Replace(swaggerDoc.basePath, string.Empty), path.Value);
}`